# Should I Use Path.GetRandomFileName or use a Guid?

Tags: c#, random, path, guid

I need to generate unique folder names, should I use [Path.GetRandomFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or just use [Guid.NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx)?

Guids say they are globally unique, `GetRandomFileName` does not make such a claim.

Comment: Guids are unique.  GetRandomFileName depends on your machine being destroyed by a meteor having higher odds than the 1 in 1E17 odds of a name collision.  Duck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think both are equally random, the difference being that `Path.GetRandomFileName` will produce a 8.3 filename (total of 11 characters) so is going to have a smaller set of unique names than those generated by `Guid.NewGuid`.

Comment: according to the link (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/180b65dd-4c1d-4f2d-b02f-117db7afa7d9/why-use-pathgetrandomfilename-instead-of-guidnewguidtostring?forum=netfxbcl) the length is 11 char

Comment: @Mzf: the example in msdn, returns `w143kxnu.idj`, so 11 random characters in the 8.3 format. Useful link though

Comment: I wonder what base GetRandomFileName uses (and thus the total output space) as it's not specified. What *is* specified, however, is that GetRandomFileName is "cryptographically strong", were a UUIDv4/GUID does not have such a claim.

Comment: The reference source for [System.IO.Path](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs#efb113f637a6bb47) shows that they have a base32 scheme. Characters a-z and digits 0-5. So figure a namespace of 32^11, or 3.6e16. GUID is larger, true, but unless he's generating a whole lot of these files . . .

Comment: Oh, and GUID isn't *random*. It'll generate unique values although you have to use the whole thing. "No proper subsequence of the bits of a GUID have the global uniqueness property." See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/04/30/guid-guide-part-two.aspx

Comment: @user2864740: just looked at the function in ilspy and it uses a-z and 0-5 to build the names (32 char)

Comment: If generating hundreds of millions of unique filenames, which would you want to use? I am guessing GUID, i'm also wondering which is most performant..